# Interval when calculating contour integral over line segment and parabola

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $\int_{C} \bar{z}dz$ along

1. line segment
2. parabola $y=x^2$

From  $(0,0)$ to $(3,9)$

For the first one, when calculating integral over line segment we use following parameterization $z(t)=z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$

is $t$'s interval always $0\leq t \leq1$ ?

For the second one, I don't understand the interval of parameterization how do we set interval for $t$ after parameterization? For this question it is

$x=t, y=t^2$

$z(t)=t+it^2$ where $0\leq t \leq3$

$
\int_0^3 (t-it^2)(1+i2t)dt=\int_0^3(2t^3+it^2+t)dt=45+9i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to parametrize (sufficiently nice) curves.  There is a standard way to parametrize line segments, and this is the one you give.  In this case, "yes", $0\leq t \leq 1$.

For the second curve, $y=x^2$, the "obvious" parametrization is $x=t, \; y=t^2$.  Then you pick the interval for $t$ so that the initial point is $(0,0)$  (so $t=0$) and the terminal point is $(3,9)$ (so $t=3$.)

But if you chose a different parametrization, the limits for $t$ might be different.

Comment: Ahh I got it I couldn't see it for some reason so it is $2\leq t \leq 4$, if initial point is $(2,4)$ and terminal point is (4,16) Thanks for the answer.